# Can't modify contact.bodyA in didBeginContact

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit and Swift. Spent too much time trying to apply position/velocity changes to a body in didBeginContact, only to read in the Apple docs that contact is read only. What is a good way to go about modifying bodies involved in a collision?

```
struct PhysicsCategory
{
    static let None: UInt32 = 0
    static let All: UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let LeftWall: UInt32 = 0b1
    static let Food: UInt32 = 0b10
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        var temp = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.7, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), size: CGSizeMake(size, size))
        temp.position.x = self.scene!.size.width/2.0
        temp.position.y = self.scene!.size.height/2.0
        temp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: temp.size)
        temp.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Food
        temp.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.LeftWall
        temp.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        temp.physicsBody!.velocity.dx = self.randomBetweenNumbers(0.0, secondNum: 0.5) - 0.25
        temp.physicsBody!.velocity.dy = self.randomBetweenNumbers(0.0, secondNum: 0.5) - 0.25
        self.addChild(temp)
    }
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Food != 0) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.LeftWall != 0)
    {
        contact.bodyA!.velocity.dx = 0.0
        println("\(contact.bodyA.velocity.dx)") //isn't 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what do you want to do?

Comment: Essentially, I want to modify the velocity of physics bodies that are involved in the collision.

Comment: I'm going to negate the velocity, so the "food" bounces off the "wall".

Comment: Maybe you can try with SKFieldNode : https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/velocityFieldWithVector:

Comment: If you want the Food nodes to bounce off the wall, set the collisionBitMask not the contactTestBitMask. Both the wall and the food bit masks need to be set, appropriately.

Comment: @0x141E, `wall.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask` does not have to be set as `PhysicsCategory.Food` since the wall is not affected by the collision.

Answer (score 0):

out of the class

```
    let firstObjectCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let secondObjectCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

    var marker:Int= 0
```

In you DidMoveToView

```
    node1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = firstObjectCategory
    node1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = secondObjectCategory
    if marker=1
    { 
        node1.velocity.dx = 0.0
    }else{
        node1.velocity.dx = what you want
    }

    node2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = secondObjectCategory
    node2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = firstObjectCategory
```

test the contact between two physic bodies :

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!)
    {
        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody


        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
        {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB

        }
        else
        {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }


        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & firstObjectCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & secondObjectCategory) != 0)
        {
          marker=1
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I've already set the categories, set them to my nodes. I'm successfully detecting collisions. The problem is that I can't modify the physics bodies are passed into didBeginContact() via the contact parameter.

Comment: Do you have only one node on your screen ?

Comment: If you just have 2 physicsBody on your screen you just have to set a marker. In you node properties write : `ìf marker=1{node.velocity.dx = 0} else {node.velocity.dx = whatYouWant}` your variable `var marker:Int = 0` need to be global (out of classes)

Comment: No. Right now, I'm testing collisions with 10 "food" blocks and one "wall" block. I guess there is no way to modify the physics bodies within didBeginContact(). Looks like much global-variable-hackery will ensue, thanks.

Comment: Ok so you need to edit just the sprite in contact with the wall?

Comment: Correct. For some reason, I'm not having any success doing so.